# Cast to a generic type

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, async-await

I have the following interfaces

```
public interface IMessageData {}

public interface IMessageSender<T> where T : class, IMessageData, new()
{
    Task<T> BuildType();
    Task SendMessage(T message);
}
```

and then a base implementation for the `IMessageSender`

```
public abstract class MessageSenderBase<T> : IMessageSender<T> where T : class, IMessageData, new()
{
    public MessageSenderBase() {
    }

    public abstract Task<T> BuildType();

    public async Task SendMessage(T message) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Sending {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message)}");
        await Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

To use these interfaces I usually create a new instance of a MessageData and create a specific implementation of MessageSenderBase like

```
public class MessageDataA : IMessageData {
    public MessageDataA() {
    }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class ASender : MessageSenderBase<MessageDataA> {
    public override async Task<MessageDataA> BuildType() {
        MessageDataA result = new MessageDataA() { Description = "description" };
        return await Task.FromResult<MessageDataA>(result);
    }
}
```

At runtime I only have in configuration the names of the `MessageSenderBase` implementations and I need to create dynamically instances of these classes and invoke both methods. This is correctly achieved with this code:

```
var className = "ASender";
var buildMethodName = "BuildType";
var sendMethodName = "SendMessage";

Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var type = assembly.GetType(className);
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

//invoke build method
var buildMethodInfo = type.GetMethod(buildMethodName);
dynamic buildAwaitable = buildMethodInfo.Invoke(instance, null);
var returnedType = await buildAwaitable;

//invoke send method
var sendMethodInfo = type.GetMethod(sendMethodName);
dynamic sendAwaitable = sendMethodInfo.Invoke(instance, new[] { returnedType });
await sendAwaitable;
```

My questions:

1. can I cast the `var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);` to a stronger type instead of leaving it as var? This would avoid me to call methods by using MethodInfo and Invoke.
2. As a further suggestion is there any way to make this design more strong typed?

Comment: 1. `var` **is** strongly typed, though implicit. In this case, it's `object`, since `Activator.CreateInstance` returns `object`. 2. You might want to look at [MEF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/).

Comment: Exactly. My question was exactly ho to cast the result of CreateInstance to a stronger type. Thanks for the MEF suggestion

Comment: @Lorenzo - You cast it like normal. `(T)Activator.CreateInstance(type)`

Comment: But the problem is that T in my case is dynamically got from a string. Could you please be more precise? thanks

Comment: Do you really need a public `BuildType` method? Couldn't you use instead a single `Task BuildAndSendMessage()` method, so that you could move it to a non-generic interface?

Comment: You might start with split message building and message sending to two different classes (after all - sending procedure should be the same for all types of messages, or at least similar). As for your current approach - generics do not work well with reflection. You either need a non-generic version of your interface, or you can just use `dynamic` (since you already ising it - I suppose you are fine with that). `dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type); var msg = await instance.BuildType(); await instance.SendMessage(msg);`

Comment: @KevinGosse: Yes. As you may see BuildType is abstract because it change for every implementation while SendMessage is built inside the base class because in 90% of the cases is always the same.

Comment: @Lorenzo It could be abstract and protected

Comment: Ohhhh. so easy?

Comment: @KevinGosse that's the solution I ended up with. if you write it in an answer I can mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bypass the issue entirely by providing a non-generic interface. Looking closely, you don't actually need to expose the `BuildType` method.

You would end up with a IMessageSender interface that exposes a single method:

```
public interface IMessageSender
{
    Task SendMessage();
}
```

Then the abstract class provides the `BuildType` method and connects everything together:

```
public abstract class MessageSenderBase<T> : IMessageSender where T : class, IMessageData, new()
{
    public MessageSenderBase() {
    }

    protected abstract Task<T> BuildType();

    public async Task SendMessage() {
        var message = await BuildType();
        Console.WriteLine($"Sending {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message)}");
        await Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> can I cast the var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type); to a stronger type instead of leaving it as var? This would avoid me to call methods by using MethodInfo and Invoke.

`var` doesn't mean untyped. It's of the type of the right-hand side expression. In this case, it's an `object`, but you can cast it to the actually expected type. However, in your dynamic scenario, there's more work needed (see below).

> As a further suggestion is there any way to make this design more strong typed?

A common solution is to have a non-generic interface for situations like you describe. The advantage is you can call the methods directly, although you have to rely on `object` instead of some specific type provided via the generic argument `T`.

The base contract of your interfaces will then look like this:

```
public interface IMessageData {}

public interface IMessageSender
{
    Task<object> BuildType();
    Task SendMessage(object message);
}

public interface IMessageSender<T> : IMessageSender where T : class, IMessageData, new()
{
    Task<T> BuildType();
    Task SendMessage(T message);
}
```

In the base implementation, an explicit implementation of `IMessageSender` will help you to hide the weakly-typed interface from its generic counterpart. The implementation will just pass the calls to the generic methods:

```
public abstract class MessageSenderBase<T> : IMessageSender<T> where T : class, IMessageData, new()
{
    public MessageSenderBase() {
    }

    Task<object> IMessageSender.BuildType() {
        T result = await BuildType();
        return result;
    }

    Task IMessageSender.SendMessage(object message) {
        return SendMessage((T)message);
    }

    public abstract Task<T> BuildType();

    public async Task SendMessage(T message) {
        …
    }
}
```

The usage is then far simpler than the original code:

```
var className = "ASender";
var buildMethodName = "BuildType";
var sendMethodName = "SendMessage";

Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var type = assembly.GetType(className);
IMessageSender instance = (IMessageSender)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

//invoke build method
var result = await instance.BuildType();

//invoke send method
await instance.SendMessage(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've ended up with a solution very similar to your based on suggestions from @KevinGosse in the question comments.